# No me refleja lo puesto en el putString

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Buenas, primero que nada estoy comenzando con esto de programación android. El punto es el siguiente. Estoy intentando crear una aplicacion en base a mis conocimientos basicos para el registro de un numero telefono el cual una vez registrado pueda enviarse unos mensajes pre definidos. El punto es el siguiente, he creado una *activity* para el registro y una para el **"Panel"**. Bien, mi problema va de que cuando registro el numero de mi activity, cuando quiero que los valores pasen al textView del panel, no se me muestra.

**Activity de registro**

```
SharedPreferences dregTele = getPreferences(context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = dregTele.edit();
editor.putString("DNumero", nTelefono.getText().toString()); //REGISTRO NUMERO TELEFONICO
SharedPreferences dregName = getPreferences(context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = dregName.edit();
editor2.putString("DName", nTransmisor.getText().toString()); //REGISTRO DEL NOMBRE DEL TRANSMISOR
editor.commit();
editor2.commit();
Intent i = new Intent(Registro.this, Seleccion.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("DNumero","");
bundle.putString("DName","");
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

Use el Shared, por que según he visto, sirve para el almacenamiento de dato interno del telefono. Ahora bien, cuando hago la transición a la activity dos que sería el **panel** solo me muestra lo que se pone en el key value del bundle.putString

```
bundle.putString("DNumero","");
bundle.putString("DName","");
```

y no muestra lo que coloco en el editText. El punto es, que debe ingresarse algo a través del editText. Almacenarlo a través del SharpedPreferences y enviarlo a la activity del panel, y poderlos usar en esa activity. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola r00t, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a 

realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a 

la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la 

comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer 

[ask]**, saludos!

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys, esta pregunta si está bien hecha. Me he dado cuenta que en muchas de las recientes preguntas sobre Android te limitas a poner el **How to ask**. La verdad es una labor muy buena, ayudas a que la comunidad SO en Español mejore, sin embargo, creo que en esta pregunta no aplica. Gracias! Tambien estoy para ayudar/aprender.

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas crear 2 `Editor`, con uno es suficiente:

```
// Obtienes los Preferences
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// Obtienes el Editor
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

// Usando el mismo Editor, guardas los 2 valores que necesitas
editor.putString("DNumero", nTelefono.getText().toString()); //REGISTRO NUMERO TELEFONICO
editor.putString("DName", nTransmisor.getText().toString()); //REGISTRO DEL NOMBRE DEL TRANSMISOR

// Confirmas los cambios en el Editor
editor.commit();

Intent i = new Intent(Registro.this, Seleccion.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("DNumero", nTelefono.getText().toString()); // Aquí debes enviar lo que tienes en tu EditText (tambien en la linea siguiente)
bundle.putString("DName", nTransmisor.getText().toString());
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i); // DName
```

Ahora, en tu activity `Seleccion.java` tendrás un método así:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xxx);

    // Aquí es en donde obtines lo que se capturó en tus EditText
    String dNumero = savedInstanceState.getBundle("DNumero");
    String dName = savedInstanceState.getBundle("DName");
}
```

Ten en cuenta, que en el método `onCreate()` estarás recibiendo los valores que envías en el `Bundle`, no los valores que guardas en `SharedPreferences`. Sin embargo, si quieres usar los valores que estan en `SharedPreferences`, así quedaría tu método `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ... mas código tuyo

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String dNumero = sharedPreferences.getString("DNumero", null);
    String dName = sharedPreferences.getString("DName", null);
}
```